# Migration failing in laravel application

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

i'm trying to run som migration to my mysqlk database, the default ones created by laravel runs fine problem happens when it starts to run queries for my own tables
Specifically the first table migration looks like this:

```php
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('polls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title')->nullable(false);
            $table->string('slug')->unique()->after('title')->nullable(false);
            $table->text('description')->nullable(false);
            $table->json('questions');
            $table->integer('max_points', false, true);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('polls');
    }
};
```

when i run php artisan migrate it gives the following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'after `title`, `description` text not null, `questions` json not null, `max_p...' at line 1 (Connection: mysql, SQL: create table` polls `(`id`bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,`created_at`timestamp null,`updated_at`timestamp null,`title`varchar(255) not null,`slug`varchar(255) not null after`title`,` description`text not null,`questions`json not null,`max_points` int unsigned not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

10  database/migrations/2023_05_18_085528_create_polls_table.php:14

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try to remove `->after('title')`

Comment: Did you try putting `after` at the end?

Comment: nothing changes, the error says that the problem is on line 14 corresponding to ```Schema::create()```

Comment: Is error still the same? It should changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't include `after()` when creating a table, only when altering it. During creation, the order of columns is determined by the order in which they appear in the migration.

[`CREATE TABLE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) does not include the `AFTER` modifier. It might be worth opening a Laravel issue to have this caught in the framework rather than trying to send an invalid command to the database.

As well, columns are `NOT NULL` by default, calling `nullable(false)` is unneeded.

Comment: luckily, the source code is documentation: `public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)`

Comment: Thanks, another fine example of where named parameters would make things clearer!